# Why doesn't this code create a Linked List?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying to create a new node at the end of the Linked List but somehow it's not working. Please Help!

```
class Node{
    int info;
    Node next;
}
Node head;


void insert(int val){
    Node nn = new Node();
    nn.info = val;
    Node cur = head;
    if(cur==null){
        cur = nn;
    }
    else{
        while(cur.next!=null){
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        cur.next = nn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for your info, you are supposed to accept and upvote correct answer and upvote other helpful answer. This expects community from everyone. Read this meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 2):

You are not changing pointer for `head` for initial case and `head` is always `null`.

```
if(cur==null){
   cur = nn;
}
```

should be

```
if(head==null){
    head = nn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `cur = nn;` to `head = nn;`

Explanation: You might be thinking that you are changing head but actually you are not. Since `head` is `null` so, on performing `cur = head` and `cur = nn`; will not save the `nn` reference to `head` it will only remain with `cur`

Comment: Explanation: You might be thinking that you are changing `head` but actually you are not. Since head is `null` so, on performing `cur = head` and `cur = nn;` will not save the `nn` reference to `head` it will only remain with `cur`

Comment: can you please mark it as answer and upvote it :) thanks

Comment: Great that this answer was found to be helpful. In future, @RICKYKUMAR please include the explanation as part of the answer - explaining why the proposed solution should work. Good work.